# UIButton does not bring up MFMailViewController

Tags: swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer, messageui

I'm having an error with a bit of code. I am new to this and I am trying to teach myself. I am finding most of my answers online but can't seem to find anything about this particular issue. I want to send an email within the app but anytime I press the email button, the MFMailViewController does not come up. It is like my UIButton isn't working. But I know I have it as an IBAction. Here is my code so far. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI

class RequestService: UIViewController,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var CustomerName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            print("Mail services are not available")

            let ComposeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
            ComposeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

            ComposeVC.setToRecipients(["jwelch@ussunsolar.com"])
            ComposeVC.setSubject("New Support Ticket")
            ComposeVC.setMessageBody(CustomerName.text!, isHTML: false)

            self.present(ComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
            // Check the result or perform other tasks.
            // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
            controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you testing this in simulator? this only works with the actual iPhone device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made an error in the syntax in your `sendMail` function. The code you posted will only open the view controller if the device *can't* send mail. Change it to this:

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        print("Mail services are not available")
        return
    }

    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    composeVC.setToRecipients(["jwelch@ussunsolar.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject("New Support Ticket")
    composeVC.setMessageBody(CustomerName.text!, isHTML: false)

    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Why do you continue to present the mail composer even if email can't be sent?

Comment: You guys know your stuff! I just changed what you said and it works flawless!

Answer (score 0):

You only attempt to display the mail controller if the device *can't* send email. That's backwards.

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        print("Mail services are not available")

        let ComposeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        ComposeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        ComposeVC.setToRecipients(["jwelch@ussunsolar.com"])
        ComposeVC.setSubject("New Support Ticket")
        ComposeVC.setMessageBody(CustomerName.text!, isHTML: false)

        self.present(ComposeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,didFinishWithResult result:MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
    // Check the result or perform other tasks.
    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And you need the delegate method outside of the other method.